# Large number of stages in my spark program

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

When my spark program is executing, it is creating 1000 stages. However, I have seen recommended is 200 only. I have two actions at the end to write data to S3 and after that i have unpersisted dataframes. Now, when my spark program writes the data into S3, it still runs for almost 30 mins more. Why it is so? Is it due to large number of dataframes i have persisted?

P.S -> I am running program for 5 input records only.

Comment: I highly recommend adding some of your spark code. Otherwise, we'll be guessing the answer at best.

Answer (score 0):

Probably cluster takes a longer time to append data to an existing dataset and in particular, all of Spark jobs have finished, but your command has not finished, it is because driver node is moving the output files of tasks from the job temporary directory to the final destination one-by-one, which is slow with cloud storage. Try setting the configuration **mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version** to 2.